# Syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO

Tags: php

1.Почему выражение `12 + echo 6;` приводит к ошибке

2.почему `print print print print 7;//7111`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ахаха )) Бросайте употреблять на ночь всякую дрянь ))

- **echo** - конструкция языка. И как же тут не быть ошибке? Вы ж не удивитесь, если при сложении **12 + "напечатать 6"**, тоже не будет нормального результата?
- по поводу второго:

  ```
  print 7; // 7 - тут всё ясно
  print print 7; // 71 - выполнение справа налево.
  ```

Первый "принт" вывел 7 и вернул единицу (true), как успешно выполненную операцию, второй - вывел на экран эту единицу. И так дальше для остальных принтов.

Comment: про принты хорошо объяснил

Comment: Ну, я ж надеюсь, что и по поводу первого всё понятно )) Т.к. **echo** это языковая конструкция, а не функция, то она не может принимать участи в математических опреациях, как составляющая часть.

Comment: это языковая конструкция, а не функция- ключевое словосочетание

Comment: @koza4ok, попросту говоря, интерпретатор воспринимает этот код как-то так:

    12 + // упс, а где ж тут логическое окончание? 
         // Ау! @koza4ok, разберись, плизз!
    echo 6;

Comment: Если быть точным, сначала выполняется _второй_ `print`.

Comment: @VladD, я ж не просто написал, что очередность выполнения "справа налево"

Comment: @Deonis: согласен, невнимательно прочитал.